# Ho to check the Model is locked using API

Tags: enterprise-architect

For checking the package is locked we can use the API pacakge.Element.locked but for model which is also an package doesn't have an element .So how can we check whether the model is locked using automation in EA.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to look into the database to get that info.

Comment: You mean you want to know whether the root node is locked? If so, why?

Comment: yes from Database we can get it but from API we cant get it

Comment: yes how to check whether is root node is locked or not

Answer (score 0):

The root package has no lock. You can see that on locking only the views below have the red exclamation mark.

I would not be astonished if you could rename the root package with the API in spite of the security being turned on.

P.S. Yes. Altering the root worked.

P.P.S.  Not only via API but also the GUI lets you rename the root package.